# Class "AppBundle\Entity\User" sub class of "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: doctrine, behat

I am writing new Behat test. New context from scratch.

```
Scenario: user visualization
  Given database is empty
    Class "AppBundle\Entity\User" sub class of "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class. (Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException)
```

The step is the following:

```
/** @Given database is empty */
public function databaseIsEmpty()
{
    $this->manager->createQuery('delete from AppBundle\Entity\User')->execute();
}
```

And the context implements KernelAwareContext that allow context to load kernel and thus also doctrine.

```
class Context implements BehatContext, KernelAwareContext
{
    private $kernel;

    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;

        $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8001',
        ]);

        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__ . "/../../AppBundle/Entity"), true);
        $conn = array('driver' => 'pdo_sqlite', 'path' => __DIR__ . '/../../../data/data.sqlite',);
        $this->manager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
    }
```

but ...

When `$this->manager->createQuery('delete from AppBundle\Entity\User')->execute();` is called, returns the error `Class "AppBundle\Entity\User" sub class of "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`

Same query, is executed in unit tests. The only difference here is that in unit tests is loaded in this way:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();
    self::bootKernel();
    $this->container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
    $this->manager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    $this->manager->createQuery('delete from AppBundle\Entity\User')->execute();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to purge whole database or a single entity? What you are saying `Given database is empty` contradicts with what you're trying to do `delete from AppBundle\Entity\User`.

Comment: Now database contains only users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a problem with your entity mappings, setup etc. first you need to sort it out. I give you fully working example so you need to work with it. First one purges every single table in database whereas the second one purges only single table.

**PURGE WHOLE DATABASE**

```
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareContext;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareContext
{
    /** @var KernelInterface */
    private $kernel;

    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
     * @Given /^the database is empty$/
     */
    public function theDatabaseIsEmpty()
    {
        $container = $this->kernel->getContainer();
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

        $purger = new ORMPurger();
        $purger->setPurgeMode(ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_TRUNCATE);
        $executor = new ORMExecutor($entityManager, $purger);
        $executor->execute([]);
    }
}
```

**CLEAR SINGLE ENTITY**

```
/**
 * @Given /^there is no user in database$/
 */
public function thereIsNoUserInDatabase()
{
    $container = $this->kernel->getContainer();
    $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    // AppBundle\Entity\User.php
    $entityManager->createQuery('DELETE FROM AppBundle:User')->execute();
}
```

Plenty of examples for you: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat

Comment: I've solved with `$this->manager = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');`

Comment: In your example `$container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');`

Comment: What is the difference?! :)

Comment: there's no difference

Comment: Lovely! By the way, better way of doing such thing is, use of tags. You tag your scenario and then the function in your context file does the rest. You don't have to write a new step like `Given database is empty`. Look at this: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/as5w/tagging-behat-scenarios-with-tagged-hooks Just an idea, not necessary.